# How do I reference a range of a non-cell range in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, offset, google-sheets-query

[Example link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dbFPXNYCAeRwqbpX1d7EapI_xxtuG5oGU8pQsZyBG4w/edit?usp=sharing)

I want to reference a part of an array or a range that is not a cell range reference. Apparently OFFSET() only works with cell references. What function do I need to reference a range of a "created" range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your case you need:

```
=QUERY(B6:D9, "select D where C = 'MAN' limit 3")
```

[image]

but offset can be done even in query:

```
=QUERY(B6:D9, "offset 2")
```